# How to redirect a page from app which is in facebook

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I have a facebook canvas app which is hosted in the facebook applications.And I want to redirect the user to my website by clicking any button in my website.How can achieve this functionality by using php code ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To redirect from the app you need to give the url of the website you in the following way

you need to include script:

```
if (isset($_REQUEST['submit'])){
    //retrieve form data here
    $name = $_REQUEST['name'];
    //save data to database or do other tasks
}

//now redirect user
header ("Location: http://apps.facebook.com/yourapplicationurl");
exit;
```